# Relative Path in Tortoise svn:externals

Tags: svn, relative-path, svn-externals

I'm using tortoise SVN to version my projects.
since they have some common libraries I'm using the external propriety in order to link the common repository.
If I use the string with the absolute path everything works fine (but other users cannot update correctly since they map the repositories in a different way.
Then I tried to use a relative path, but i get this error:

Error: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Error: Unable to open repository 'file:///Z:/..DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository'

file:///Z:/DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository 2.WebDev\Framework

../../../../DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository 2.WebDev\Framework

the repository is located in Z:/DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository, how can I set the relative in order to update correctly?

thank you
Andrea

Comment: Can you share the exact values you've used?

Comment: they are the real values:
the repository of the project is Z:/COMPANY_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/Repository/2.WebDev/Framework (this is not a real path)
the common code is in
Z:/DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository

Comment: Please note that you can edit the original question when you need to provide further info; code in comments is unreadable. Whatever, you say you got that error when using a relative path but all your paths begin with `Z:/` thus are *not* relative.

Comment: The string I'm using ins svn:externals is ../../../../DMF_FRAMEWORK/Repository (as mentioned in the question) that's the relative path that is not working